# Running jQuery Script for Each Div on Page Load

Tags: jquery, css

I've been wracking my brain and searched through this site and others to figure out why the script I'm running only works on the first div that I run it on.  I need this script to find all the instances of this class and modify its css.  It's a vertically centering script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".innerDiv").css('top', ($(".outerDiv").height() - $(".innerDiv").height()) / 2);
    });
</script>
```

This is the example of the HTML it should be running on.

```
<div class="outerDiv" style="height:calc(100% - 20px); background:red;">
    <div class="innerDiv" style="max-height:100%; position:relative; background:green;">
        <textarea style="width:90%; height:100px; color:black; background:#CCC; resize:none; font-size:24px;"></textarea>
        <div style="height:10px;"></div>
        <span class="button">RESET</span>
        <span class="button">SEND</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe because you have only 1 div with the class `innerDiv`?

Comment: Hi Larry, I've setup the pen here:http://codepen.io/xszaboj/pen/woMzMG?editors=1010. Can you tell me what is wrong on that example?

Comment: Dekel, this was an example of one of the divs it needs to call that script on. The other divs use the same class name. Xszaboj, I'll try this as soon as I'm home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `$(".innerDiv").css('prop', 'value');` would change that property to that value on every `$(".innerDiv")`, your problem comes in when you use `$(".outerDiv").height()` and `$(".innerDiv").height()` as part of that value calculation.  There, jQuery uses the first one it finds, and it doesn't refer to the specific innerDiv/outerDiv pair you're trying to target.

For that, you need to use `.each()`:

```
$(".innerDiv").each(function() {
    $(this).css('top', ($(this).parent().height() - $(this).height()) / 2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

need to set the height for `.outerdiv` as it it taking same height as of `.innerdiv`. check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/r742x4up/#&togetherjs=akVLtR8xOI)

Jquery:

```
 $(".innerDiv").css('top', ($(".outerDiv").height() - $(".innerDiv").height()) / 2);
```

Html:

```
<div class="outerDiv" style="height:200px; background:red;">
    <div class="innerDiv" style="max-height:100%; position:relative; background:green;">
        <textarea style="width:90%; height:100px; color:black; background:#CCC; resize:none; font-size:24px;"></textarea>
        <div style="height:10px;"></div>
        <span class="button">RESET</span>
        <span class="button">SEND</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of giving height in 'px' if you want to do it in % then you can do it using css as well. Refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/frvjv3ff/#&togetherjs=akVLtR8xOI)

HTML:

```
<div class="outerDiv" style="height:100%; background:red;">
    <div class="innerDiv" style="max-height:50%; position:relative; background:green;">
        <textarea style="width:90%; height:50%; color:black; background:#CCC; resize:none; font-size:24px;"></textarea>
        <div style="height:10px;"></div>
        <span class="button">RESET</span>
        <span class="button">SEND</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .outerDiv {
        position : absolute;
    width:90%;
        height : 100%;
        background-color : #123456;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .outerDiv:before {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .innerDiv {
        height : 50%;
        width : 90%;
        background-color : #FFFFFF;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```